# Why does restriction on a page does not work

Tags: java, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have a page named **register** and I want to restrict access to this page only to the predefined hybris user **anonymous**. in order to achieve that, I created the ImpEx bellow

```
INSERT_UPDATE CMSUserRestriction; $contentCV[unique = true]; &userRestriction; name       ; uid[unique = true]       ; users(uid); pages($contentCV, uid)
                                ; ; anonymousUserRestriction ; Anonymous User Restriction ; anonymousUserRestriction ; anonymous ; register
```

After that, I logged in with a b2bcustomergroup user to the storefront and I still have access to the register page.

ps: I have checked the backoffice, and the ImpEx is imported successfully in the initialization phase.

Comment: Is the restriction synced to online?

Comment: @geffchang yes it is synced to online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think restrictions like this will only work for pages accessed as content pages, i.e. label attribute contains the page URL.  These are accessed via a default controller that evaluates restrictions.

The programmatic pages directly reference the page ID in their controller method, their controllers are annotated with the URLs & do not typically reference CMSRestrictions.  To control access to these you would use the Spring Security setup: look for spring-security-config.xml in your storefront extension